# Retrieve individual element from JSONObject in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a `JSONObject` and I want to retrieve the individual elements from it. I am able to get the header values out but, not able to fetch the individual elements. Below is my JSON request:

JSON Request:

```
{"Context":{"HealthCloudIndividual":{"Id":"41cb7f2c-a3a7-4a31-80fa-ce43102f5650","EffectiveDate":2004}},"Metadata":{"schemaVersion":"v1","publishTimestamp":2005,"eventType":"IndividualEmailVerification","docTimestamp":2007},"Publisher":{"Application":{"Desc":"ABCD","Code":"EFGHIJKL"}},"Profile":{"Email":"abc@xyz.com","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Prefix":"Mr.","Key":{"Key2":"Value2","Key1":"Value1","Key6":"Value6","Key5":"Value5","Key4":"Value4","Key3":"Value3","Key7":"Value7"}}}
```

I need to retrieve the elements inside `Profiles` tag:

```
Profiles ::{"Email":"abc@xyz.com","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Prefix":"Mr.","Key":{"Key2":"Value2","Key1":"Value1","Key6":"Value6","Key5":"Value5","Key4":"Value4","Key3":"Value3","Key7":"Value7"}}
```

My Java Class:

```
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(message.getPayload().toString());
    LOG.info("JSON Request: {}", jo);
    LOG.info("Profiles ::" + jo.get("Profile"));

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();


    Map<?, ?> map = objectMapper.readValue(message.getPayload().toString(), Map.class);

    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        LOG.info("Map Values:::::" + entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
        LOG.info("Map Profile Values:::::" + entry.getValue());

        if (entry.getKey().toString().contains("Profile.FirstName")) {
            LOG.info("FirstName::::" + entry.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
```

This code doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hm, does the mapping to `Map` actually work? Doesn't it fail with an exception? And what are the contents of the map you're getting?

Comment: This is what my output look like after the run:


2020-02-11 12:23:52.177  INFO 28386 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1]   : Map Profile Values:::::{FirstName=John, LastName=Doe, Prefix=Mr., Email=abc@xyz.com, Key={Key2=Value2, Key1=Value1, Key6=Value6, Key5=Value5, Key4=Value4, Key3=Value3, Key7=Value7}}

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get into the individual elements using the below:

Map mp1 = new HashMap<>();
`mp1 = (Map<String, String>) entry.getValue()`

Comment: Mark this as answer and close the question..  Otherwise, people will still try to answer this.